# PHP - How can I assign a name to my array key instead of an int with array_push

Tags: php

Hey everyone, I have a database result that returns from a method. I need to push 4 more values onto the stack but I need to name the keys. array_push() automatically assigns an int. How can I overcome this behavior?

```
Array
(
    [these] => df
    [are] => df
    [the] => sdf
    [keys] => sd
    [ineed] => daf
    [0] => something
    [1] => something
    [2] => something
    [3] => something
)
```

The keys that are int values need to be changed. How can I do this using array_push?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the four *values* you want to use are already in an associative array themselves, you can use `+` to merge the two arrays:

```
$array1 = array('these' => ..., 'are' => .., 'keys' => ...);
$four_entries = array('four' => ..., 'more' => ..., 'keys' => ..., '!' => ...);

$merged_array = $array1 + $four_entries;
```

Comment: Now that's cool! Thanks, had no idea. I'm unfortunately getting the exact same results tho. There is an int preceeding each new value.

Comment: Thank you.. I figured it out.. :)

Answer (score 6):

Just like this:

```
$arr['anotherKey'] = "something";
$arr['yetAnotherKey'] = "something";
$arr['andSoOn'] = "something";
```

or

```
$arr = array_merge($arr, array(
    'anotherKey' => "something",
    'yetAnotherKey' => "something",
    'andSoOn' => "something"
));
```

...but I'd recommend the first method, since it merely adds more elements to the array, whereas the second will have a lot more overhead (though it's much more flexible in some situations).

Answer (score 3):

Why not

```
$arr["whateveryouwant"] = something
```

> Note: If you use array_push() to add
>   one element to the array it's better
>   to use $array[] = because in that way
>   there is no overhead of calling a
>   function.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add more entries to the array, all you need to do is:

Existing array;

```
$array = 
{
    "these" => "df"
    "are" => "df"
    "the" => "sdf"
    "keys" => "sd"
    "ineed" => "daf"
}
```

Adding to the array

```
$array["new_key1"] = "something";
$array["new_key2"] = "something";
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the help. The first array is built a bit different than the second and admittedly, I'm not very good with arrays so I'm trying to figure out how to use your method. I already tried it before posting but I couldn't get it to work right.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign the name you do not use the `array_push` function, you just assign the element:

> `$array['somekey'] = 'somevalue';`

So, in short, you can't do that using `array_push`.

Comment: Ok, you probably saved me a bunch of time trying to figure it out. Thanks!